# route_hierarchical whit href and anchor

Tags: dart

I'm using route_hierarchical, and I'm trying to handle a route.

When I put directly an URL like localhost/#/test, it work. But when I try from `<a href='#/test'></a>` nothing happen.

Have you an idea about my mistake ?